# What are the most standard and efficient way to represent a timeseries in F# and/or OCaml

Tags: f#, ocaml, time-series

I wanted to know what are the most standard and efficient ways to represent a timeseries in F# for timeseries including the sparse/nonsparse cases and the regular interval/non-regular interval cases.

Does anyone has experience with what is a standard way to represent these with this language or in OCaml ?

I started by representing them by an array but realised that an array cannot contain information such as the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what are the common operations that you are most likely to use with those timeseries.

- If you'll do only sequential access, then exposing a timeserie as a sequence of timedvalue might be good.

like so

```
type TimedValue<'T> = { ts : DateTime; value: 'T}
type TimeSerie<'T> = TimedValue<'T> seq
```

- If you intend to have some exact search, you could wrap that with a Map

like so

```
type TimeSerie (vals : TimedValue<double> seq) = 
   let mdata = Map.ofSeq (vals |> Seq.map(fun x -> x.ts, x ))

   static member inline LinearReturn vb  ve = ve / vb - 1.
   static member inline LogReturn vb ve = log ve - log vb

   member x.toReturns(times : TimeCollection, f) =
         times |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.map(fun (l,n) -> {tfrom = l; tto= n; value= f (mdata.[l].value) (mdata.[n].value) } )

   member x.toLinReturns(times : TimeCollection) = x.toReturns(times, TimeSerie.LinearReturn)
   member x.toLogReturns(times : TimeCollection) = x.toReturns(times, TimeSerie.LogReturn)
```

Comment: If the samples are equally spaced, is there a way to have a list which has some kind of attributes containing information such as the ticker of the stock, the start, end and the frequency of the series without losing the ability to manipulate the elements like an array ?

Comment: @BlueTrin - Wrap the array in a record and add record fields for any attributes you need. Or if you want transparent access to the underlying array, you could use a class with a default indexed property.

Comment: @petebu: I am not too sure about what you mean because I am beginning in F#, but I will google this and try to see some sample code ...

Comment: @BlueTrin : you need to think at how you will access the data. for instance if it will be through random access for time potentially not in your collections, then you might want to create an internal 'interval tree'. if you will access it in increasing time anyway, an enumerator would suffice. if you know you have equally spaced data, or are ok to pretend they are (say calendar time = trading time) then you dont need from and to dates. etc.. take some time to know what you want to do with the said time serie

Comment: @nicolas: in your first example how can I create a sequence of 50 days with values from 1 to 50 as a test ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Functional Reactive Programming is the answer : it's a paradigm in which you bind events to function and define "behaviors" and signal which evolve all the time.

Time and events are represented in a well designed way.

Some links to start :
http://erratique.ch/talks/react-ocamlum-2010.pdf
http://erratique.ch/software/react

an other lib : https://github.com/jaked/froc